# Disabling scroll wheel acceleration on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mouse, scrolling

So I've been issued a nice new Macbook Air from work.

When I use it with a mouse, the scroll wheel is driving me absolutely nuts. There's such a high degree of acceleration that I find it impossible to use accurately --- a small movement only goes a couple of pixels, while a large movement goes too far.

I want linear scroll wheel response, the way Linux and Windows does it. (But with normal acceleration for mouse movement.) Does anyone know how to do this?

Note: I've searched for an answer here, and there *are* some duplicates, but they're all years old and haven't been touched for ages. I'm hoping for some new information.

Answer (score 7):

I was in the same boat, so I decided to dig in and figure it out myself.

I've coded something that changes properties on the HIPointing device to greatly ease the acceleration (it's not as insane as the original one), check it out:

https://github.com/jfdno/DisableExtremeScrollAcceleration

I managed to turn it off, but when I do the scrolling increments are way too small (and I haven't figured out how to scale them back up). This should at least make it more usable for the time being. Look at the docs.

Comment: this fixed the issue for me, this software has 2 different authors (seems to have been forked), and this version works on mavericks.

Comment: Appears to be only here now: https://github.com/davekeck/DisableExtremeScrollAcceleration

Answer (score 0):

[SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com/) donationware works great for me on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

Comment: This is for mouse tracking, not mouse scroll.